# Ruby club two multi-dimensional key into 1 via date and other key elements

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I just began to work on ruby Sinatra.

I am having an issue over creating an array from an existing array.
I have this array which is grouped by date and each of the elements contain all the entries of that day.

```
{
    "2015-05-15": [{
        "minutes": 25,
        "key1": [{
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "some key": "0/0"
        }],
        "key3": [{
            "some key": "5/5"
        }],
        "key4": [{
            "some key": 0.48
        }],
        "key5": [{
            "some key": "0.6"
        }],
        "key6": "2015-05-15"
    }, {
        "minutes": 25,
        "key1": [{
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "some key": "0/0"
        }],
        "key3": [{
            "some key": "5/5"
        }],
        "key4": [{
            "some key": 0.48
        }],
        "key5": [{
            "some key": "0.6"
        }],
        "key6": "2015-05-15"
    }],
    "2015-05-25": [{
        "minutes": 25,
        "key1": [{
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "some key": "0/0"
        }],
        "key3": [{
            "some key": "5/5"
        }],
        "key4": [{
            "some key": 0.48
        }],
        "key5": [{
            "some key": "0.6"
        }],
        "key6": "2015-05-25"
    }],
    "2015-06-10": [{
        "minutes": 25,
        "key1": [{
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "some key": "0/0"
        }],
        "key3": [{
            "some key": "5/5"
        }],
        "key4": [{
            "some key": 0.48
        }],
        "key5": [{
            "some key": "0.6"
        }],
        "key6": "2015-06-10"
    }, {
        "minutes": 25,
        "key1": [{
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "some key": "0/0"
        }],
        "key3": [{
            "some key": "5/5"
        }],
        "key4": [{
            "some key": 0.48
        }],
        "key5": [{
            "some key": "0.6"
        }],
        "key6": "2015-06-10"
    }]
}
```

I want to club this array such that all the sub element arrays are arranged via keys for each date. For example the following array is what I am looking for. Here all the sub arrays in date `2015-05-15` are clubbed into one key element.

```
 {
    "2015-05-15": [{
        "minutes": 50,
        "key1": [{
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        },
        {
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "some key": "0/0"
        },{
            "some key": "0/0"
        }],
        "key3": [{
            "some key": "5/5"
        },
        {
            "some key": "5/5"
        }],
        "key4": [{
            "some key": 0.48
        },
        [{
            "some key": 0.48
        }],
        "key5": [{
            "some key": "0.6"
        },
        {
            "some key": "0.6"
        }],
        "key6": "2015-05-15"
    }],
    "2015-05-25": [{
        "minutes": 50,
        "key1": [{
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        },
        {
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "some key": "0/0"
        },{
            "some key": "0/0"
        }],
        "key3": [{
            "some key": "5/5"
        },
        {
            "some key": "5/5"
        }],
        "key4": [{
            "some key": 0.48
        },
        [{
            "some key": 0.48
        }],
        "key5": [{
            "some key": "0.6"
        },
        {
            "some key": "0.6"
        }],
        "key6": "2015-05-25"
    }],
    "2015-06-10": [{
        "minutes": 50,
        "key1": [{
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        },
        {
            "some key1": "14",
            "some key": "subject here"
        }],
        "key2": [{
            "some key": "0/0"
        },{
            "some key": "0/0"
        }],
        "key3": [{
            "some key": "5/5"
        },
        {
            "some key": "5/5"
        }],
        "key4": [{
            "some key": 0.48
        },
        [{
            "some key": 0.48
        }],
        "key5": [{
            "some key": "0.6"
        },
        {
            "some key": "0.6"
        }],
        "key6": "2015-06-10"
    }]
}
```

I tried to arrange them using a custom method I created.

```
def self.iterateArray(array)
    result = Hash.new  #{ |h, k| h[k] = [] }
    count =  0
    result[count] = Array.new(7)

    array.each { |key, data|

      result[count]["date"] = key
      data.each { |k, d| 

        k.each { |key_, data1|
          if key_ == 'key1'
            result[count][key_] += data1
          end
          if key_ == 'key2'
            result[count][key_] << data1
          end
          if key_ == 'key3'
            result[count][key_] << data1
          end
          if key_ == 'key4'
            result[count][key_] << data1
          end
          if key_ == 'key5'
            result[count][key_] << data1
          end
          if key_ == 'key6'
            result[count][key_] << data1
          end
        }
      }
      count += 1
    }
    puts "result: #{result}"  
    result
  end
```

But every time I try to run this method I am getting weird errors like "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" at

```
result[count]["date"] = key
```

earlier it was creating such error at `result[count]` but then I initiated it with

```
result[count] = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
```

And system started pointing to the next element.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or Tell me how can I deal with such problems or how custom arrays are created.. Any help is appreciated.

Guys, I apologize for adding 2 "key2" elements there. It was actually key1 .. to key6 elements. I have updated the sample arrays.

Comment: _"I have this array which is grouped by date "_ - Excuse me but you don't have an array. That is a Hash.

Comment: How do you decide that it will be `"key5" => "2015-05-15"` in output, and not `"key5" => ["2015-05-15", "2015-05-15"]` unlike other keys? All the other keys have array of values.

Comment: Also `key2` appears twice in each `Hash` which means that one the second one will exist (probably throws a warning to tell you about this). e.g. `{key2: 1, key2: 2} #=> {key2: 2}`

Comment: I apologize for adding 2 "`key2`" elements there. It was actually `key1` .. to `key6` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved my answer using this method I created. Here I have removed the "date" field as it was getting repeated.

```
 def self.iterateArray(array)
    response = []
    array.each { |key, data|
      result = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }

      result["date"] = key
      result["minutes"] =0
      result["key1"] =[]
      result["key2"] =[]
      result["key3"] =[]
      result["key4"] =[]
      result["key5"] =[]
      data.each { |k, d| 

        k.each { |key1, data1|
          if key1 == "minutes"
            result[key1] += data1
          elsif key1 != "date"
            result[key1] << data1[0]
          end
        }
      }
      response << result
    }
    response
  end
```

But I still don't like the way we need to declare all variables within the array before adding value to them. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problems in your question

- You have key `"key2"` twice in each hash (both input and output). So, the latter one will override the values of first assignment. From engineersmnky's example: `{key2: 1, key2: 2} #=> {key2: 2}`
- You have not explained the complete logic to convert your input into output.
- Don't know if the resulting hash is to be prepared considering the type of values i.e. `Integer`, `Array`, etc. or is it key specific i.e. always sum up values for key `"minutes"` without checking its type.

#### Solution

So, though i am not sure about the logic behind your expected output, i was able to convert your original array to it:

**Input:**

```
input = {
  "2015-05-15" => [{
    "minutes" => 25,
    "key1" => [{
        "some key1" => "14",
        "some key" => "subject here"
    }],
    "key2" => [{
        "some key" => "5/5"
    }],
    "key3" => [{
        "some key" => 0.48
    }],
    "key4" => [{
        "some key" => "0.6"
    }],
    "key5" => "2015-05-15"
}, {
    "minutes" => 25,
    "key1" => [{
        "some key1" => "14",
        "some key" => "subject here"
    }],
    "key2" => [{
        "some key" => "5/5"
    }],
    "key3" => [{
        "some key" => 0.48
    }],
    "key4" => [{
        "some key" => "0.6"
    }],
    "key5" => "2015-05-15"
}],
"2015-05-25" => [{
    "minutes" => 25,
    "key1" => [{
        "some key1" => "14",
        "some key" => "subject here"
    }],
    "key2" => [{
        "some key" => "5/5"
    }],
    "key3" => [{
        "some key" => 0.48
    }],
    "key4" => [{
        "some key" => "0.6"
    }],
    "key5" => "2015-05-25"
}],
"2015-06-10" => [{
    "minutes" => 25,
    "key1" => [{
        "some key1" => "14",
        "some key" => "subject here"
    }],
    "key2" => [{
        "some key" => "5/5"
    }],
    "key3" => [{
        "some key" => 0.48
    }],
    "key4" => [{
        "some key" => "0.6"
    }],
    "key5" => "2015-06-10"
}, {
    "minutes" => 25,
    "key1" => [{
        "some key1" => "14",
        "some key" => "subject here"
    }],
    "key2" => [{
        "some key" => "5/5"
    }],
    "key3" => [{
        "some key" => 0.48
    }],
    "key4" => [{
        "some key" => "0.6"
    }],
    "key5" => "2015-06-10"
  }]
}
```

**Procedure:**

```
output = {}

input.each do |date, ary|
  keys = ary.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq    # Returns all the keys in all the hash elements for given date

  hash = {}

  keys.each do |key|
    if ary.all? { |e| e[key].is_a?(Integer) }
      hash[key] = ary.inject(0) { |sum, h| sum + h[key].to_i }    # Assuming you want to sum up values for keys with integer values
    elsif ary.all? { |e| e[key].is_a?(Array) }
      hash[key] = ary.inject([]) { |sum, h| sum + h[key] }        # Assuming you need `+` operation on the array values too 
    elsif ary.all? { |e| e[key].is_a?(String) }
      hash[key] = ary[0][key]                                     # Assuming string values are same in all the elements of array
    else
      raise "Invalid type for value of key: #{key}"
    end
  end
  output[date] = [hash]     # I don't know why are we putting it in array as it will always be one element only. You could do: `output[date] = hash`
end
```

**Output:**

```
output
 => {"2015-05-15"=>[{
       "minutes"=>50,
       "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"},
                {"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
       "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}, {"some key"=>"5/5"}],
       "key3"=>[{"some key"=>0.48}, {"some key"=>0.48}],
       "key4"=>[{"some key"=>"0.6"}, {"some key"=>"0.6"}],
       "key5"=>"2015-05-15"}],
     "2015-05-25"=>[{
       "minutes"=>25,
       "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
       "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}],
       "key3"=>[{"some key"=>0.48}],
       "key4"=>[{"some key"=>"0.6"}],
       "key5"=>"2015-05-25"
     }],
     "2015-06-10"=>[{
       "minutes"=>50,
       "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"},
                {"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
       "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}, {"some key"=>"5/5"}],
       "key3"=>[{"some key"=>0.48}, {"some key"=>0.48}],
       "key4"=>[{"some key"=>"0.6"}, {"some key"=>"0.6"}],
       "key5"=>"2015-06-10"
     }]
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your effort. I tried your solution, its showing me errors at every key. First show me error on minutes, "Invalid type for value of key: minutes" I updated the `is_a? Integer` to `Float`, next showing error for `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def convert(h)
  h.each_with_object(Hash.new { |e,k| e[k]={} }) do |(date, v),f|
    v.each { |g| f[date].update(g) { |_,ov,nv|ov.is_a?(Array) ? ov+nv : ov } }
  end
end
```

**Example**

Due to the large size and formatting of the example it is difficult to recognize the forest for the trees. The first thing I did was pare down the example to its essential structure. I reduced the numbers of keys (date strings) from three to two and reduced the number of keys in each hash. I also used indentation to clarify the structure. By doing so I obtained the following.

```
h = {
  "2015-05-15"=>[
    { "minutes"=>25,
      "key1"=>[{ "some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here" }],
      "key2"=>[{ "some key"=>"5/5"}],
      "key5"=>"2015-05-15"
    },
    { "minutes"=>25,
      "key1"=>[{ "some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here" }],
      "key2"=>[{ "some key"=>"5/5" }],
      "key4"=>[{ "some key"=>"0.6" }],
      "key5"=>"2015-05-15"
    }
  ],
  "2015-06-10"=>[
    { "minutes"=>25,
      "key1"=>[{ "some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here" }],
      "key2"=>[{ "some key"=>"5/5" }],
      "key5"=>"2015-06-10"
    },
    { "minutes"=>25,
      "key1"=>[{ "some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here" }],
      "key2"=>[{ "some key"=>"5/5"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
convert(h)
  #=> { "2015-05-15"=>{
  #       "minutes"=>25, 
  #       "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"},
  #                {"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
  #       "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"},
  #            {"some key"=>"5/5"}],
  #       "key5"=>"2015-05-15",
  #       "key4"=>[{"some key"=>"0.6"}]},
  #     "2015-06-10"=>{
  #       "minutes"=>25,
  #       "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"},
  #                {"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
  #       "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"},
  #                {"some key"=>"5/5"}],
  #       "key5"=>"2015-06-10"
  #     }
  #   }
```

This result differs slightly from what was requested. The value of each date string key (e.g., `"2015-05-15"`) was to be an array containing a single element (a hash). The is no purpose to having arrays that always contain a single element, so I've simplified by making the values of the date strings hashes.

**Explanation**

`Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]={} }` causes `h[k]` to be set equal to an empty hash when `h` does not have a key `k`. See the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that employs a block.

I've used the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the values of the three block variables,`k`(common key),`ov`("*old value*") and`nv` ("*new value*" )

The code is more-or-less equivalent to the following.

```
f = {}
h.each do |date, v|
  v.each do |g|
    f[date] = {} unless f.key?(date)
    f[date].update(g) { |_,ov,nv| ov.is_a?(Array) ? ov+nv : ov }
  end
end
f
```

If this is still not clear try running this code with some `puts` statements added.

```
f = {}
h.each do |date, v|
  puts "date=#{date}"
  puts "v=#{v}"
  puts "f=#{f}"
  v.each do |g|
    puts "  f=#{g}"
      if f.key?(date)
        puts "  f has key date=#{date} so f[#{date}] is not set to {}"
      else
        puts "  f does not has key date=#{date} so f[#{date}] is to {}"
      end
    f[date] = {} unless f.key?(date)
    f[date].update(g) { |_,ov,nv| ov.is_a?(Array) ? ov+nv : ov }
    puts "  f[#{date}]= #{f[date]}"
  end
end
f
```

This prints the following.

```
date=2015-05-15
v=[{"minutes"=>25, "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}], 
                   "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}], "key5"=>"2015-05-15"},
   {"minutes"=>25, "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
                   "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}], "key4"=>[{"some key"=>"0.6"}],
                   "key5"=>"2015-05-15"}]
f={}
f={"minutes"=>25, "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
                  "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}], "key5"=>"2015-05-15"}
f does not has key date=2015-05-15 so f[2015-05-15] is to {}
f[2015-05-15]= {"minutes"=>25,
                "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
                "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}], "key5"=>"2015-05-15"}
f={"minutes"=>25, "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
                  "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}],
                  "key4"=>[{"some key"=>"0.6"}],
                  "key5"=>"2015-05-15"}
f has key date=2015-05-15 so f[2015-05-15] is not set to {}
f[2015-05-15]= {"minutes"=>25,
                "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"},
                         {"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
                "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"},
                         {"some key"=>"5/5"}],
                "key5"=>"2015-05-15",
                "key4"=>[{"some key"=>"0.6"}]}
```

```
date=2015-06-10
v=[{"minutes"=>25,
    "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
    "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}],
    "key5"=>"2015-06-10"},
       {"minutes"=>25,
        "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
        "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}]}]
f={"2015-05-15"=>{"minutes"=>25,
                  "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}, 
                          {"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
                  "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"},
                          {"some key"=>"5/5"}],
                  "key5"=>"2015-05-15", 
                  "key4"=>[{"some key"=>"0.6"}]}}
f={"minutes"=>25,
   "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
   "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}],
   "key5"=>"2015-06-10"}
f does not has key date=2015-06-10 so f[2015-06-10] is to {}
```

```
f[2015-06-10]= {"minutes"=>25,
                "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
                "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}], "key5"=>"2015-06-10"}
f={"minutes"=>25,
   "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}],
   "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}]}
f has key date=2015-06-10 so f[2015-06-10] is not set to {}
f[2015-06-10]= {"minutes"=>25,
                "key1"=>[{"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"},
                         {"some key1"=>"14", "some key"=>"subject here"}], 
                "key2"=>[{"some key"=>"5/5"}, {"some key"=>"5/5"}], 
                "key5"=>"2015-06-10"}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here, what you suggested the solution I assume `h` will be an input and output as well. Is that correct? I tried it and it is showing me the same result as the input. It's not working as the sample output you have shown.

Comment: Curious, yes, I used the variable `h` in several different places, but they referred to distinct values because each was defined within it's own scope. For example, the variable `h` in `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]={} }` is confined to the scope of its enclosed block, so it has nothing to do with the variable `h` which holds the input hash. Think of it as two methods using the same variable. Obviously,  those variables are unrelated to each other. I edited my answer to use different variables for different hashes, but that's just cosmetic.

Comment: So my questions remain the same. If I had to use your solution, what should be my input and output? If the solution works, its very interesting to see 3 line solution  and I would like to know how will it work in my case. PS: I have corrected the array samples I added earlier. I mistakenly added `key2` twice. I really apologize for this mistake.

Comment: The input is the hash `h`. The three lines of code,when executed, return the hash I refer to above as the “desired return value”.  That is the output.

Comment: I reorganized my answers and added more explanation.